# Unable to mount hugetlbfs in non-root docker container

Tags: docker, dpdk, huge-pages

Trying to run a dpdk app in a container without the --privileged option to docker run.

I've created the hugetlbfs mounts on the host machine (e.g., `mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /tmp/mnt/huge`)

```
# mount | grep huge
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,hugetlb)
nodev on /tmp/mnt/huge type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
```

However, within the container I get:

```
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: 64 hugepages of size 1073741824 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Failed to get current mempolicy: Operation not permitted. Assuming MPOL_DEFAULT.
EAL: set_mempolicy failed: Operation not permitted
EAL: set_mempolicy failed: Operation not permitted
EAL: Failed to get current mempolicy: Operation not permitted. Assuming MPOL_DEFAULT.
EAL: set_mempolicy failed: Operation not permitted
EAL: set_mempolicy failed: Operation not permitted
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: rte_service_init() failed
```

I've tried both setting the ownership of the mount point to the non-root-user as well as trying to bind the mount point in various ways (e.g., `-v /mnt/huge:/mnt/huge -v /dev/hugepages:/dev/hugepages`). I've even tried non-standard mountpoints and passing `--huge-dir non/standard/mountpoint` to the eal_args.

One stackoverflow answer suggested using the `--device` option (e.g., `--device /dev/hugepages`), but for /dev/hugepages or /dev/hugetlbfs I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: linux runtime spec devices: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/hugepages": not a device node.
```

I've also passed in a lot of syscaps like sys_rawio, sys_admin, sys_resource, but doubt those are the issue.

It seems like people have been able to do it in the past. Not sure if there are new features in docker that lock down memory further in containers preventing what I'm trying to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: a quick check is there any mounted path for huge pages on the system? Can you please check with 'mount -a'. And update the ticket

Comment: @VipinVarghese -- I updated the question and show the mountpoints related to hugetlbfs

Comment: For dpdk application if default mount path is not used one has to pass the custom mount path which is '/tmp/mnt/huge'. My recommendation is first run dpdk without docker as non rootfirst on host. Then if it fails in docker it is permission issue. Then try pass '/TMP/mnt/' using -v

Comment: For dpdk application if default mount path is not used one has to pass the custom mount path which is '/tmp/mnt/huge'. My recommendation is first run dpdk without docker as non rootfirst on host. Then if it fails in docker it is permission issue. Then try pass '/TMP/mnt/' using -v

Comment: @VipinVarghese -- Ok, I must have forgotten to include the --huge-dir in my last run or something. I have it running outside the container. I have updated the question with the new actual error. It does seem to be a permission thing. I get "Failed to get current mempolicy: Operation not permitted"

Comment: That's good because now path related is done and it isore of permission and issue. Please try chown and -v docker option to resolve it.

Comment: @VipinVarghese chown -R myuser:myuser /tmp/mnt/huge performed, and I pass -v /tmp/mnt/huge:/tmp/mnt/huge with the docker run command, and it doesn't change anything. Still get the same error.

Comment: As mentioned in earlier comments were you able to run as non root on host (no docker) for the dpdk version in use? If yes, then the issue is related to docker permission. Happy to debug with you

Comment: I was able to run as non-root on host (no docker). So yes, must be a docker permission issue. If I pass --privileged to the docker run command it also works. Not sure how to debug with you.

Comment: were you able to change the ownership for vfio to non root user? is RT permission issue resolved with ownership?

Comment: no, I gave up on the hugetlbfs working. The only thing I could get working is bypassing hugepage support: "--legacy-mem",
"--no-huge",
"-m",
"4096"

Comment: thanks for the update, after couple of look up depending upon the distro and permission the best bet is to use `--single-file-segements & --legacy-mem` but with huge page. Thanks for the try